# Extract inline images from Lotus Notes using Lotus Notes Java API

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm having issues to extract inline images that are pasted in the email body if the emails are sent from external email (like gmail for example) into the Lotus notes.

The emails which are sent from Lotus Notes itself has no issues and I'm able to retrieve the inline images by using the `document.generateXML()` method and parsing through `<picture>` tag the stream.

My real concern is how to extract from the external emails (like gmail).

Comment: I'm curious why you are trying to extract the images, but mostly want to see the code you've already tried to use to extract them successfully from a Notes document. If you show us your code, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Its my project requirement. This is the way I extract attachments. `Session session = GetAwdNotesConnection.getAwdNotesSession();`
`Vector attachmentList=session.evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc);` `get images String xmlString= document..generateXML(); `
Using xml I can extract inline image are attached via lotus note email. appreciated for your help and time

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in that a MIME inline attachment is not the same as a Notes attachment. When the mail comes in, if the File component is over a certain size it will create a $FILE you can interact with.

However in some cases, or low file size this attachment remains within the MIME data. Which you can't get to with the Java API.

You can tell the server to force attachments to be stored as $FILE by using the following notes.ini setting.

```
MIMEForceAttachments=1
```

This will only change new mails coming in. Also it will treat every object that is not text and inline as an attachment. So images may also be converted.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the image into another program (e.g. Paint, Ifranview) if you edit the Email. Steps:

```
1) Highlight the Email in the main Inbox view  
2) Action -> Edit  
3) Select image and copy  
4) Open Ifranview and paste the image, Save it
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste seems to work for images if you open the message in a new window

Right click on the message and select 'Open in New Window'.  Now right click on the image and select copy.
Now you can Paste the image into paint, Word etc.  I have lotus notes 8.5 and this works for me